# Ruby: Treating a class like a number?

Tags: ruby

I want to mix roman numerals with arabic numerals when doing some math.

I would define some classes for each symbol

```
class I
end

class V
end

class X
end
```

Now I want to be able to say things like

```
5 + V   # results in 10
X + 12  # results in 22
```

But am not sure where to start.
I would have to define a method that tells ruby how `5 + V` works, give each class a value, and when I say

```
I
```

I should get the value 1.

What kind of methods should I look at that allows me to treat `X` as the number 10?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why use classes instead of constants?

Comment: Is this homework? As Rob points out it's puzzling that you want to use classes. In general the reason to create a class is so you can create instances of the class. Are you ever going to call e.g. `V.new`?

Comment: @RobDavis Being able to do math on classes sounds useful to know. It can be extended to more complex operations. Like, actual roman numeral arithmetics.

Comment: @Keikoku Roman numeral arithmetic is the _same_ as normal arithmetic - it's just substitution of symbols. `XI + I` is exactly the same as `11 + 1`. If anything, you _might_ want something that will just print the arithmetic as roman numerals.

Comment: I guess in practice I would just modify how the results are displayed. Maybe roman numerals was a bad example. I probably should've went with something like different currencies with their own exchange rates and performing arithmetics between different currencies lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems really simple to me:

```
V = 5
V + 1 #=> 6
```

If you want to show the result as roman numerals, I would extend the `Fixnum` class with a `to_roman` method:

```
class Fixnum
  def to_roman
    # I'll leave the implementation up to you
  end
end
```

With this you can do:

```
10.to_roman #=> "X"
```

Comment: Can constants be easily adapted if I wanted to display the results in roman numerals rather than arabic numerals?

Answer (score 0):

You could overwrite the + operator in your roman class, so that would works for X + 12, but not for 12 + X. See this blog post: http://strugglingwithruby.blogspot.ca/2010/04/operator-overloading.html for more infos

See

> The definition is not commutative, i.e., trying to do 3 + a would fail. To get that to work you would need to override the addition method in Integer - and I think that would be a bad idea.